# The view app_name.views.signup didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. for a existing username

Tags: python, django

the signup view is working for new users but when i try to signup an existing user, my view returns nothing.

views.py

```
def signup(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        userObj = form.cleaned_data
        name = userObj['username']
        email = userObj['email']

        if not (User.objects.filter(username=name).exists() or User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()):
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('app_name:home')

        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Looks like a username with that email or password already exists')
else:
    form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'app_name/signup.html', {'form':form})
```

form.py

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField(required='True')
first_name = forms.CharField(required='True')
last_name = forms.CharField(required='True')

class meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email',
    'username',
    'password1',
    'password2',
    )

def save(self, commit='True'):
    user = super(SignUpForm, self).save(commit='False')
    user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
    user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
    user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']


    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

i want the form to return a message stating that the user already exist. can't see where the problem is. it sends None.

Answer (score 0):

The root problem is that you don't return anything if the form is not valid, because your final `return` line is indented inside the `if` statement. It need to be moved back one indent.

But a lot of what you're doing here is pointless. Validation belongs in the form, not in the view; in fact the form will *already* be validating that the username is unique, so in that case the form won't be valid and your own check won't even be hit. Remove that code; if you do need to validate email uniqueness you should do that explicitly in a `clean_email` method on the form.

Also, your form save method replicates what the form is already doing. You should remove it.